# Unable to create SYC Sybase ASE database profile in powerbuilder 9.0

Tags: powerbuilder

Following is the error message we are receiving:

> Unable to load requested database Interface. Please make sure both the
>   interface and client software are properly installed.

We have ASE 15.0 installed on our server.
Can anyone please advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 15 of Open Client they changed the names of the .dll files so now PBSYC90.DLL cannot find them.

There is a bat file in the Open Client install folders that will make copies of the files with the old names.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help us. We ran the copylibs.bat file present in ..\OCS-15_0\Scripts folder which is responsible for changing the name of dll files but still we are facing the same issue.

Comment: Is PBSYC90.DLL in C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder?

Comment: Is C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder and the Open Client folders in the system path? Try running dsedit from the Run box on the Start menu and use it to ping your server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. PBSYC90.dll is present in C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder path.
Both the paths you have mentioned are present in system path variable. We were able to ping our server successfully using dsedit. Still we are unable to create database profile for ASE 15.0. I would also like to mention that we have Powerbuilder 12.0 installed on the same server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. We were able to resolve our issue by running "copylibs.bat create" command through command prompt.